# Xamarin Forms, a ViewModel gets data to the property, but doesn't show in the View

Tags: xamarin.forms, view, viewmodel

I have a 2 Views and 2 ViewModels, the first one has a button for each category that sends a value to the ViewModel Command, which push the second View/ViewModel with the data sent.

That data is received on the second ViewModel but the View is empty.

What could be the problem with that?

**The photos are from the second View/ViewModel.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMeUq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMsbG.png)

Comment: Please paste code text directly into question, rather than using images. Then people can copy it - to search keywords, add to their answer, or use in general.

Comment: It is likely that there are two **instances** of second viewmodel. Somewhere in code not shown, there is another place where you ask for that viewmodel. Instead, you'll need to get the viewmodel ONCE, then use it both places. This is easier to do in c# code, rather than in xaml. **Add to question** **1)** xaml for one of the buttons that sets a property on second viewmodel. **2)** any code or xaml that creates second viewmodel, via `service` or `new`. **3)** The *constructor* of second view (where InitializeComponent is done).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so @ToolmakerSteve was right, the problem was that there was two instances of the second viewmodel, thanks to you @ToolmakerSteve :)